# "IndexError: too many indices" using HDF5 file with 8760 - every hour for the year

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Background:** I am trying to pull out the daily max windspeed from an 8760 hdf5 dataset using a kdtree to lat/lons from a point file and then pull it all into a csv. Things go smoothly, until I try to make an empty array to store the max values. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic needed here.

I have browsed other questions and from other answers think I may have a one-dimensional array and I'm trying to slice it with two dimensions. But not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# Store X / Y coordinates
x_vector = []
y_vector = []

# Open dummy HDF5 file
hf = h5py.File(dir + 'h5/wspd_2014.h5', 'r')

# Break out attributes of the data
ws = hf['wspd'][...]
meta = hf['meta'][...]

# Get coordinates of HDF5 file
coords = np.vstack([meta['latitude'], meta['longitude']]).T

# Open the vector data
with fiona.open(dir + 'shapefiles/soil_winderode4.shp', 'r') as vector:
    # create array to store xy coordinates
    coords_arr = []
    # get the coordinates from the shapefile
    for feature in vector:
        coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
        coords_arr.append(coords)

# Run a loop using the coordinates and split the x and y
for x, y in coords_arr:
    x_vector.append(x)
    y_vector.append(y)

# Run the kdtree to match nearest values
tree = cKDTree(np.vstack([x_vector, y_vector]).T)
kdtree_indices = tree.query(coords)[1]

# ------ Match WSPD, lat/lon & Save to CSV -------
ws_sites = ws[:, kdtree_indices]
indices = range(0, 8760, 24)
indices.append(8759)
```

**Issue:** This is where things get wonky, I make an empty numpy array using days (365) and the shape of windspeed (194940) in the `for`loop and then my intent is to get the max value for every day (ind).

```
out = np.empty(shape=(365, ws.shape[1]))

for ind in range(len(indices)-1):
    out[ind, :] = ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind + 1], :].max(axis=0)
```

**As per request here is the traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
194940
  File "meera_extract.py", line 56, in <module>
out[ind, :] = ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind + 1], :].max(axis=0)
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: It always helps if you put the full traceback into your question, to show the actual error.

Comment: Is it the access of `ws_sites` that yields the error, or the assignment into `out`? Have you tried a line with just `ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind+1],:]`, nothing else, to see if that yields an error?

Comment: @Evert Thank you, I added the traceback to the post. I tried removing  `out[ind, :] =` and it still yields that error when running `ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind + 1], :].max(axis=0)` by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there was some indentation missing below the `with ... a vector:`.  I added my guess on that.  But I'm guessing all of that `hdf5` stuff is unimportant - at least for your problem.

The problem is all at the end - if I read your question right:

```
ws_sites = ws[:, kdtree_indices]
indices = range(0, 8760, 24)
indices.append(8759)
#.... 
out = np.empty(shape=(365, ws.shape[1]))

for ind in range(len(indices)-1):
    out[ind, :] = ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind + 1], :].max(axis=0)
```

From this I deduce that `indices` is a list with values in the range 0 8760, 366 values in all.  `out` is 2d, so indexing it with `ind` should be fine.

But what about `ws_sites`?  What is its shape?  Any time you have indexing errors, check the shapes.  Often they aren't what you might guess.  You are indexing it as though it were 2d, eg.

```
ws_sites[24:48, :]
```

It looks like `ws` is 2d.  But if `kdtree_indices` is a single number, `ws_sites = ws[:, kdtree_indices]` will be 1d, producing the `too many indices`.

The error has to do with the number of dimensions, not their size.  Trying to index with too high a number will produce a different error.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that the code never seems to paste right when posting here and my indents always seem off. I ran `print ws_sites.shape` and it came back with `(8760,)` so yes it seems your conclusion is correct that `ws_sites` is 1d.

Comment: Is there a work around where I can make it 2d, but nan or null until I run the `for` loop and the `out[ind, :] = ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind + 1], :].max(axis=0)`?

Comment: `ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind + 1]].max()` produces one value, the max over that slice of `ws_sites`.

Comment: so I need add a second dimension? What if I add the `min` as well as the `max`? For example `for ind in range(len(indices)-1):
    out[ind, :] = ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind + 1], :].max(axis=0), \
                  ws_sites[indices[ind]: indices[ind + 1], :].min(axis=0)`

Comment: That might work if `out` has 2 columns. Experiment.  Or collecting these values in a list or list_comprehension. `out = [ws_sites[...].max() for ind in range(...)]`.